# How to download large files (1 GB minimum) in angular with .net core Web API?

Tags: angular, .net-core, download, asp.net-core-webapi, large-files

I have been developing a system that needs to download files. A file is at least 1 GB in size. On my local machine, it took me hardly 10 seconds to download the file but when I perform the same operation on the server, it takes more than 2 hours to download.

I have used angular for forntend and in backend there is .net core 5.

Below is the angular code.

```
 public GetFile<R>(actionName: string, param: any = null): any {
    let response = null;
    const uri = `${this.BaseUrl}${actionName}?keyname=${param.keyname}`; 
    const options: Object = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
      observe: "body",
      reportProgress: true,
      responseType: "blob"
    };
    
    response = this.http.patch<R>(uri, param, options)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError<string>(`Get file [${actionName}] failed`))
    );
    return response;
  }
```

Below is the .net core code.

```
[HttpPatch]
[Route("DownloadJobResult")]
public async Task<ActionResult> DownloadJobResult(string keyname)
{
    IScheduler scheduler = await _factory.GetScheduler();

    JobKey key = new JobKey(keyname);

    IJobDetail result = await scheduler.GetJobDetail(key);

    string physicalPath = result.JobDataMap.GetString("FILENAME_ON_DISK");
    string downloadFileName = result.JobDataMap.GetString("DOWNLOAD_FILENAME");

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(physicalPath) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(downloadFileName))
        return NotFound();

    var memory = new MemoryStream();
    using (var stream = new FileStream(physicalPath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
    }
    memory.Position = 0;

    return File(memory, GetContentType(physicalPath), downloadFileName);
}
```

In both places, there is the same code. On local and on the server as well. But I cannot figure out why it takes too much time to download from the server.

This is the server info:

```
OS: Windows Server 2019
Memory: 8 GB
Storage: 100 GB
```

Please help.

Let me know if you need some more information.

Comment: Maybe you can test your Internet speed,if the speed is low,it will take too much time to download from the server.

Comment: I checked my internet speed, it is pretty okay. It's 150 Mbps. I believe it is quite enough to download large file.